# Inquiry/Response, Yes/No interface with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sms, chatbot

I am a noob in the StackOverflow community, as we as a javascript/jquery noob. I am trying to put together a chat interface which would resemble SMS text messages. I am currently allowing user to enter text input, and have javascript look out for specified keywords (Yes/No) and show a specific hidden div in my html to simulate a response.

I have been trying to leverage a CodePen example (https://codepen.io/adobewordpress/pen/wGGMaV) which has gotten me pretty far. But I am also looking for duplicate Yes/No responses from the user, which if the user says "Yes" to multiple questions, javascript is serving up the FIRST Yes/No response.

I need a way to wrap my questions and look for specific user input answer per question, once input is received, serve the correct response- THEN move to the next question, which will also look for a Yes/No response from the user. Upon their response then serve question 2 response from javascript. Move on to Question 3, look for Yes/No response. Etc.

Any and all help is much appreciated. Hopefully even as a noob I can understand and work through any helpful responses.

My current CodePen (https://codepen.io/therise03/pen/bYXVLK) is using the above explaination of logic, but would like it to be using my condition workflow as typed out below.

**Desired flow:**

Condition1 [
    Question: Would you like to continue your magazine subscription? Text CONTINUE to continue or NO to stop {

```
If Yes: go to Condition2
If No: “Thanks you are not subscribed”
```

}]

Condition2 [
    Question: Your total will be $XXXX.XX. Would you like to pay for your order with your card on file? Text YES to continue or NO to stop. {

```
If Yes: go to Condition3
If No: “OK we will not use card on file”
```

]

Condition3 [
    Question3: We need to confirm your shipping address for this order.  Is 123 Main Street; O’Fallon, MO  63368 correct? Text YES to continue or NO to stop. {

```
If Yes: “OK address confirmed”
If No: “Address not confirmed”
```

]

Comment: though this might not answer your question fully, I thought this was an interesting exercise and built my own solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VrovoM?editors=1010. I know it's almost completely different code, but thought I'd share it.

Comment: wow! This is basically exactly what I am trying to do! I am going to study your code and see if I can wrap my head around it. I have one final question: after Question 3, yes answer, SMS response with "ok address confirmed" I want to wait another 2seconds and now ask another question with yes/no response. ex. Question 3 (answered and response given)....wait 2 seconds....Question 4 presented to user. The codepen you put together only shoots another question once the previous was answered. Can I force another question if the previous one doesn't need a response from the user?

Comment: sorry if that was long winded, to be more clear: I want to simulate a completed order with a messageFromThem response. Then seconds later initiate another messageFromThem but this time as a yes/no question like the previous.

Comment: so you want to send a response that is not a question, followed by a response that is a question?

Comment: after Condition3 (address confirmed) I want to have a response that says "ok we will text you when we ship your order", then seconds later, another response that says "order shipped! Would you like to auto-enroll your subscription?" in another chat bubble (fromThem)

Comment: granted not clean, at all, here is a possible solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POMbNw?editors=0010

Comment: this is amazing. Yeah you hit it right on the head! Only thing I noticed is, I think when new workflow comes in, scrollDown() doesn't seem to kick in. Thank you so much! You have been an enormous help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our conversation in the comments, I thought I'd submit an answer.

I thought it would be a good exercise for me to build a solution for this, while not clean, it works and you can improve it.

**I have only made changes to the JS from your codepen.**

> codepen: codepen.io/anon/pen/POMbNw?editors=0010

Here is the code in case that codepen is not available anymore:

js:

```
/* START: HELPERS */

function appendFromThem(msg){ // append a "fromThem" msg
  $('<div class="message"><div class="fromThem"><p>'+msg+'</p></div></div>').insertAfter('.message:last');
}

function appendFromMe(msg){ // append a "myMessage" msg
  $('form.chat div.messages').append('<div class="message"><div class="myMessage"><p>' + msg + '</p></div></div>');
}

function isString(str){ // check if param is a string
  return jQuery.type(str) === "string";
}

function areEqual(str1, str2){ // check if strings are the same after trimming and setting to lower case
  if(!isString(str1) || !isString(str1)) return str1 === str2; // either of them is not a string, use the normal "==="
  return str1.trim().toLowerCase() === str2.trim().toLowerCase();
}

/* END: HELPERS */

// workflow types
var WF_TYPE = {
  Q: "question",
  END: "end",
  NEW: "new" // start new workflow after cuttent one
}

/*
 * The workflow object
 * each sub-object should have a "msg" and responses typically "yes" and "no"
 */
var wf = {
  type:WF_TYPE.Q,
  msg:"Would you like to continue your magazine subscription? Text CONTINUE to continue or NO to stop.",
  continue:{
    type: WF_TYPE.Q,
    msg:"Your total will be $XXXX.XX. Would you like to pay for your order with your card on file? Text YES to continue or NO to stop.",
    yes:{
      type:WF_TYPE.Q,
      msg:"We need to confirm your shipping address for this order.  Is 123 Main Street; O’Fallon, MO  63368 correct? Text YES to continue or NO to stop.",
      yes: {
        endMsg: "OK address confirmed",
        msg: "some new question?",
        type : WF_TYPE.NEW,
        yes:{
          msg: "OK cool.",
          type: WF_TYPE.END
        },
        no:{
          msg: "NOT cool...",
          type: WF_TYPE.END
        }

      },
      no: {
        msg:"Address not confirmed",
        type:WF_TYPE.END
      }
    },
    no:{
      msg: "OK we will not use card on file",
      type: WF_TYPE.END
    }
  },
  no:{
    msg:"Thanks you are not subscribed",
    type: WF_TYPE.END
  }
}

/*
 * Transitions current workflow to the next based on user response
 * @param msgFromUser the msg that user typed
 * @returns a response object containing the new workflow, response and other options
 */
function transition(currentWorkflow, msgFromUser){
  console.log('getResponse start', currentWorkflow, msgFromUser);
  if (currentWorkflow.type === WF_TYPE.END){
    return {
      wf: $.extend({}, currentWorkflow)
    }
  }
  else if (currentWorkflow.type === WF_TYPE.Q){
    var newWorkflow;
    var found = false; // if a user reponse was found in current workflow
    $.each(currentWorkflow, function(key, val){ 
      if(!found && key !== "msg" && areEqual(key, msgFromUser)){ // check if user msg matches any of the valid responses
        newWorkflow = $.extend({}, val); // cone the value
        console.log("found it", newWorkflow)
        found = true;
      }
    });

    return {
      wf: newWorkflow ? newWorkflow : $.extend({}, currentWorkflow),
      errorResponse: found ? undefined : "Sorry, we didn’t understand your response. Please try again."
    }
  }
  else if(currentWorkflow.type === WF_TYPE.NEW){
    return {
      wf: $.extend({}, currentWorkflow)
    }
  }
}


function scrollDown() {
  var focusBottom = document.getElementById("textMessage");
  focusBottom.scrollTop = focusBottom.scrollHeight;
}


$("input").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) { // if user clicked enter, submit
    event.preventDefault();
    $('form.chat input[type="submit"]').click();
  }
});

//appendFromThem(wf.msg);
$('form.chat input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
  $input = $('form.chat input[type="text"]');
  event.preventDefault();
  var message = $input.val();
  appendFromMe(message);
  $defered = $.Deferred();
  var responseAndWf = transition(wf, message); // get response from workflow
  if(responseAndWf){
     wf = responseAndWf.wf;
     var response = responseAndWf.errorResponse ? responseAndWf.errorResponse : wf.msg;
     setTimeout(function() {
       if(wf.type !== WF_TYPE.NEW){
         appendFromThem(response);
       }
       scrollDown();
       $defered.resolve();
     }, 1500); 
  }

  if(wf.type === WF_TYPE.NEW){

    $defered.then(function(){
      appendFromThem(wf.endMsg);
      wf.type = WF_TYPE.Q;
      setTimeout(function() {
      appendFromThem(wf.msg);
      },2000)
    });
  }
  $input.val('');
  scrollDown();
});
```

CSS:

```
input, textarea, [contenteditable] {
    color: #666;
    caret-color: blue;
}

body {
    background: #fff; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:16px;


}

h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Rubik';
    font-weight: 400;
}


::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
 color:    #cdced2;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
 color:    #cdced2;
 opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
 color:    #cdced2;
 opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
 color:    #cdced2;
}
::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
 color:    #cdced2;
}
form.chat .myMessage, form.chat .fromThem {
    max-width: 90%;
}



form.chat *{
  transition:all .5s;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

form.chat {
  margin:0;
  cursor:default;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
  user-select: none;   
    border:0 none;
}

form.chat span.spinner{
  -moz-animation: loading-bar 1s 1;
  -webkit-animation: loading-bar 1s 1;
  animation: loading-bar 1s 1;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #00e34d;
  transition: width 0.2s;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0; right:0;
  z-index:4
}

form.chat .messages{
  display:block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position:relative;
  height:90%;
  width:100%;
  padding:1% 3% 7% 3%;
  border:0 none;

}

form.chat ::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 3px; height:1px;transition:all .5s;z-index:10;}
form.chat ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: white;}
form.chat ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #bec4c8; 
  border-radius:3px;
}

form.chat .message{
  display:block;
  width:98%;
  padding:0.5%;
}

form.chat .message p{
  margin:0;
}

form.chat .myMessage,
form.chat .fromThem {
  max-width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}



form.chat .myMessage,.fromThem{
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  clear: both;
  font: 400 15px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

form.chat .myMessage {
  background: #00e34d;
  color:white;
  float:right;
  clear:both;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px 0px\9;
}

form.chat .myMessage:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -8px;
  height: 19px;
  border-right: 20px solid #00e34d;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 0px\9;
  transform: translate(-1px, -2px)\9;
}

form.chat .myMessage:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -42px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}

form.chat .fromThem {
  background: #E5E5EA;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  clear:both;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px 0px\9;
}
form.chat .fromThem:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -7px;
  height: 19px;
  border-left: 20px solid #E5E5EA;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 16px 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -2px);
  transform: translate(0, -2px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 0px\9;
  transform: translate(-1px, -2px)\9;
}

form.chat .fromThem:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
  transform: translate(-30px, -2px);
}

form.chat date {
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  font-size:14px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color: #8b8b90;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:4;
}

form.chat .myMessage date {
  left: 105%;
}

form.chat .fromThem date {
  right: 105%;
}

form.chat input{
  /* font: 400 13px 'Open Sans', sans-serif; */
  font: 400 1em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    border:0;
 /* padding:0 15px; */
    padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
  height:10%;
  outline:0;
}

form.chat input[type='text']{
  width:73%;
  float:left;
}

form.chat input[type='submit']{
  width:23%;
  background:transparent;
  color:#00E34D;
  font-weight:700;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}

  form.chat .myMessage,form.chat .fromThem{
    font-size:1.1em;

  }



  form.chat .myMessage,
  form.chat .fromThem {
    max-width: 90%;
  }

@-moz-keyframes loading-bar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  90% {
    width: 90%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loading-bar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  90% {
    width: 90%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes loading-bar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  90% {
    width: 90%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* DEMO */
.iphone{
  /* 
    width:300px;
  height:609px;
  background-image:url('http://www.adobewordpress.com/tasarim/images/iphone6.png');
  background-size:100% 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
    */
    width:100%;

}

.border{
    /* position:absolute;
    top:12.3%;right:7%;left:7%;bottom:12%;
    overflow:hidden; */
}

a.article{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:15px;left:15px;
  display:table;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  background-color:#00e34d;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font: 400 15px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="iphone">
  <div class="imessage-header"></div>
  <div class="border">
    <form class="chat">
      <span></span>
      <div class="messages" id="textMessage">
        <div class="message">
          <div class="fromThem">
            <p>Would you like to continue your magazine subscription? Text CONTINUE to continue or NO to stop.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message magPrice" style="display:none;">
          <div class="fromThem new">
            <p>Your total will be $XXXX.XX. Would you like to pay for your order with your card on file? Text YES to continue or NO to stop.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message addressVerification" style="display:none;">
          <div class="fromThem new">
            <p>We need to confirm your shipping address for this order.  Is 123 Main Street; O’Fallon, MO  63368 correct? Text YES to continue or NO to stop.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message goToWeb" style="display:none;">
          <div class="fromThem new">
              <p>To change your shipping address go to this <a href="#">website</a>.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;border:1px solid #ddd;width:100%;z-index:101;background-color:#fff;height:50px;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your message" autofocus style="height:auto;">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" style="height:auto;">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just wanted to include that adding in `scrollDown()` function just after the line: `appendFromThem(wf.msg);` toward the bottom of the script - kickstarted the scroll to bottom again after each message is delivered. When we get "address verified", then another message would show after a couple seconds, this was not keeping the user towards the bottom. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Sure, but thats not the primary question, this answer is far from perfect solution, but it addresses you question :)